# python socket programming settimeout() timer not reset each call

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

The `settimeout(10)` function will reset it's timer to `10` when each time I call `connectionSocket.recv(1024)`

I want the timer only be reset if I send `active` to the server. Like this:

```
timeOut = 10
connectionSocket.settimeout(timeOut)
while 1:
    sentence = connectionSocket.recv(1024)
    if sentence.decode() == 'active':
        #reset the timer of settimeout()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an application level constraint, not something that TCP can handle for you.

You can set the timeout to an acceptable error margin (eg. if you want to wait 10s total, a timeout of 1s would give you 11s in the worst case) and handle the timeout of the transaction yourself.